# Commit and Push button is disabled in Katalon Studio when trying to commit changes

Tags: gitlab, commit, katalon

I am using Katalon version - 8.5.5 . Have been able to commit and pull changes successfully from Gitlab to Katalon. But now for me the Commit and Push button is disabled (greyed out). No changes to setting/configuration made recently. I am able to pull from gitlab successfully via Katalon.

Any help here please.

[image]

Has anyone faced this issue... I am able to pull but unable to commit.